# How do I run a cloud function continuously (ala Cloud Job) using Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, parse-server

I have a cloud function, let's say it is as follows.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("averageStars", function(request, response) {
  var query = new Parse.Query("Review");
  query.equalTo("movie", request.params.movie);
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      var sum = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; ++i) {
        sum += results[i].get("stars");
      }
      response.success(sum / results.length);
    },
    error: function() {
      response.error("movie lookup failed");
    }
  });
});
```

I want this cloud function to execute continuously every x number of hours on Google App Engine. Where would I move the above function and what modifications would I need to apply to make this happen?

Edit: Based on https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/#push_queues_and_pull_queues, GAE doesn't appear to support task queues for nodejs so the task would have to execute using some other tool.

Comment: did you try _cron jobs_?

Comment: No I have not, if that is the only way I would accept an answer that shows how to do it on GAE for the above cloud function.

Comment: just follow official docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml